# Weight painting - Suddenly unable to remove paint

Tags: weight-painting

Suddenly unable to remove paint with 0 weight in Add mode or 1 weight in Subtract, same issue in Mix. It paints in all configurations of blend, weight, radius and strength. Gone through all the other stuff *I can think of* like lock modes, mirrors, shading, overlays. Vertex groups aren't locked. Tried reparenting and restarting Blender. I must have clicked something I shouldn't somewhere, because it's been fine all day.

Comment: Please [edit] your question add add images of your interface that help to visually describe your problem. Thanks.

Comment: I solved the problem, Tim. I had made a mess of weight painting and emptied all the vertex groups to start again from a clean slate. Auto Normalize was still enabled in Tool Options thus preventing me from subtracting (or adding with 0 weight). When I tried reparenting, I did so with empty weights because the mesh is messy and inadvertedly recreated the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I'd emptied my vertex groups after making a mess of painting and had Auto Normalize selected in Tool Options when I started over. This seems to have prevented me from removing paint. I'm guessing all groups have to contain some weight before Auto Normalize can be employed?

Comment: Well, 2 groups have to contain some weight.  Otherwise, you remove the weight, and then autonormalize immediately restores it, because the only way to have normalized weights-- weights that sum to 1-- is set the weight of the one group to 1.